# What battery should I use on a rarely used vehicle?

Tags: battery

I own a 2001 Toyota Camry that I rarely use. I only drive once a month or so, but can go two or three months without driving at all.

Considering the tendency of a SLA battery to die when drained is there some type or model of battery which would be better for me than a regular SLA battery? My current battery is dead and I'm just jumping the car off a little plug in jump starter every time I drive now.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

From looking around, SLA should still last long enough for your intervals, although this depends a lot on temperature. That said, they still may not like it as much.

I'd just recommend picking up a good SLA and an appropriate [Battery Tender](http://www.batterytender.com/Battery-Tender-12V-1.25A-International-Battery-Charger_4) (or something similar) and connecting it at somewhat regular intervals or just leaving it connected when you're not using the car and letting [Float Mode](https://chargetek.com/basic-information.html) do the work.

Doing this should keep your battery for many, many, years barring some unusual circumstance. Check [this section](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/archive/can_the_lead_acid_battery_compete_in_modern_times) covering SLA batteries. Based on the info here, you *could* opt for an AGM if you wanted to, but the considerably cheaper SLA option should totally cover your needs if the battery is kept charged and healthy.

Comment: Darn you! Stole my answer, you did! +1 ;o)

Comment: @Paulster2 Lol! ;)